# ios5 Twitter lock?

Tags: objective-c

I have a question i my app i integrated Twitter but.

How can i put a 'lock' on 'ios5 intergrated Twitter' so you not can change the text of the tweet?

```
TWTweetComposeViewController *tweetSheet = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];
[tweetSheet setInitialText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" %d 'yes!!", counter]];
```

Can someone help me with this small problem?

Does anyone know how i can do this?

Need some more information? Please ask me!

Answer (score 1):

You **can't** do this on iOS using `TWTweetComposeViewController` .

It would be extremely furstating as a user if you present a Twitter dialog but didn't allow you to edit it, which is why it doesn't have that functionality.

Comment: It would also be "corralling" people to tweet what you insisted they did.